# Collision detection using distance field for a dynamic object

Tags: collision-detection, signed-distance-field

I am using a signed distance field for collision detection. The object I calculated the distance field for rotates between 0 and -30 degrees. The other object I want to check collision against is in a bounding volume hierarchy (BVH) of axis aligned boxes. The problem is that as the first object is rotating, I cannot use the initial calculated distance field for collision detection. One solution that I thought of is that I can rotate the Bounding volumes by an angle opposite to what the original object rotates and then check the collision but this can be computationally extensive. Is there any other better solution that I can use to check the collision with the rotating object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution you described is the correct one. You would convert the other objects to the local coordinate system of the object with the SDF and then use the SDF to check for collisions.